Decomposition of quark field
I´m currently reading the book "Heavy quark physics" from Manohar/Wise. To compute a matrix element one needs the decomposition of a quark field in terms of nonrelativistic constituent fields. The book says
$q=\begin{pmatrix}
    q_{nr}(\uparrow)\\
    q_{nr}(\downarrow)\\
    -\overline{q}_{nr}(\downarrow)\\
    \overline{q}_{nr}(\uparrow)\\
\end{pmatrix}$
plus additional derivative terms probably arising from the Taylor expansion. My question is how does one obtain this form for the spinor and why is a minus sign in the third entry of the Dirac spinor?

Regarding "Where does the minus sign come from?", it is easy to see that $q=q_{nr}\oplus [M \overline{q}{nr}]$, where $M^2=-\mathrm{Id}{2\times 2}$. This is nothing but a real/imaginary part decomposition because the group which acts over $q$ has for algebra $\mathfrak{spin}^\mathbb{C}(4) \simeq \mathfrak{spin}(1,3)\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} \simeq \mathfrak{spin}(1,3) \oplus i \mathfrak{spin}(1,3)$. So $q$ is just a way to write a "complex spinor" (even though a spinor has complex-valued components).
